# How can we parse cronExpression to get the next trigger date in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, cronexpression

I want to parse the cronExpression like ('0 0 8 13 * ?) to get the next trigger-Date in javascript.

eg. Cron String (0 0 10 ? * MON-FRI)  Class runs Monday through Friday at 10 AM.
I need to calculate next trigger date in the format (dd-mm-yyyy) 15-10-2012.

Please share the code-snippet or algorithm for above problem?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: this [cron parser](https://github.com/bunkat/later/blob/master/lib/cron.parser.js) may help

Comment: Can you please share the algorithm for cronExpression Parsing? I tried to write code, but get confused in middle of code.I don't want to consider time( Sec Min Hours). I want only the next trigger date.